# Merge two list into a list of dictionaries with multiple keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two list like

```
my_list1 = ["Harry", "Bob"]
my_list2 = ["21", "23"]
```

I want to form a dictionary like:

```
[{"name": "Harry", "age":"21"}, {"name": "Bob", "age":"23"}]
```

in an efficient way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
my_list1 = ["Harry", "Bob"]
my_list2 = ["21", "23"]
new_data = [dict(zip(['name', 'age'], i)) for i in zip(my_list1, my_list2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'age': '21', 'name': 'Harry'}, {'age': '23', 'name': 'Bob'}]
```

Or:

```
[{'name':a,'age':b} for a, b in zip(my_list1, my_list2)]
```

Comment: The 2nd one is better